# Agregando etiquetas a partir de un campo de ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, script, wordpress-plugin

acabo de terminar de crear un fragmento de código que me permite crear un `término` dentro de una `taxonomía` a partir del valor de un campo de `Advanced Custom Fields`:

```
$arr  = get_field('ocupacion');
$ocup = array_values(array_filter($arr)); // delete NULL

wp_insert_term(
    $ocup[0], // the term 
    'etiqueta_npc', // the taxonomy
    array(
        'slug' => $ocup[0],
        'parent' => $parent_term['term_id']  // get numeric term id
    )
);
# Relaciona una publicacion con un termino y tipo de taxonomia
wp_set_object_terms($post->ID, $ocup, 'etiqueta_npc');
```

Así es como se ve en el frontend:

Partiendo del modo edición se ve así:

*Se elige la ocupación a partir de un campo de selección multiple de ACF, en este caso **`Herrero`***
[image: modo edicion. Seleccion de Ocupacion]

Al guardar y mostrar la página, en efecto, se añade la etiqueta a partir de la ocupación elegida:

[image: Etiqueta en el front end]

Y si entramos nuevamente al modo edición se puede apreciar la etiqueta generada a partir de la ocupacion, en la lista de etiquetas disponibles:

[image: Etiqueta listada a partir del campo ocupacion]

### El problema

Si bien las etiqeutas se agregan perfectamente, incluso más de una etiqueta (el campo `ocupación` es un array y permite seleccionar varias ocupaciones de la lista), al momento de agregar de forma manual una etiqueta diferente a cualquiera de las del campo ocupacion, ésta no se agrega, y no aparece por ningún lado.

No tengo idea de cómo agregar los términos en su funcionalidad por defecto además de los que se generan a partir del campo de ACF, lo ideal seria poder agregar tanto términos de forma manual y términos por medio de un array a partir de un campo de ACF, al mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

### Resuelto

```
$arr  = get_field('ocupacion');
$ocup = array_values(array_filter($arr)); // delete NULL

wp_insert_term(
    $ocup[0], // the term 
    'etiqueta_npc', // the taxonomy
    array(
        'slug' => $ocup[0],
        'parent' => $parent_term['term_id']  // get numeric term id
    )
);
# Relaciona una publicacion con un termino y tipo de taxonomia
wp_set_object_terms($post->ID, $ocup, 'etiqueta_npc');
```

Para agregar términos a una publicación manteniendo los términos que ya tiene, se debe pasar a `true` el parámetro `$append`:

```
wp_set_object_terms($post->ID, $ocup, 'etiqueta_npc', true);
```

En caso contrario se mostrarán solamente los nuevos términos.